# ssh multiple server for tar operation

Tags: shell-script, ssh, parallelism

I have a file containing IP address of 10 servers. e.g `host.txt`

I want to tar a directory and on 10 differents server from 1 server.

How can I run ssh parallel to those server which can reduce my exceution time

I have tried below code, but no luck.

```
cat host.txt |
 while read i
 do 
    ssh -qn $i 'tar -cvf /tmp/TC.tar.gz /etc' &
 done
```

Expectation:

Want to parallel SSH the 10server, so that the tar command will execute parallelly on server without using PSSH.

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need to escape the & or the shell gets greedy.

Comment: Look into Ansible. Will make your job a lot easier if you handle lots of server's.

Comment: Why without PSSH?

Answer (score 1):

Use clusterssh: https://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/

To execute commands in parallel, you use it like

```
cssh user@client1 user@client2
```

This you get a terminal window for each client and a commandwindow to type commands on any terminal in parallel.

There are many options to set inside ~/.clusterssh directory, so it is easy to group your clients by tags.

To bundle clients from your `host.txt`, the file `~/.clusterssh/tags` may look like this:

```
root@host1 tar update
root@host2 tar update
root@host3 tar test
root@host4 update test
root@host5 update test
```

This way you define the tags tar, update and test. You can use the tag `tar` to run clusterssh  on the first three hosts by running `cssh tar`.

Search the internet for `clusterssh` and you'll find a lot of helpful docs.

Most linux distros contain clusterssh so you may install it easily by e.g. `apt-get install clusterssh`.

Edit:

You may add your command to clusterssh to be executed use the `-a` option:

```
cssh tar -a "tar -cvf /tmp/TC.tar.gz /etc"
```

And if you use ssh public/private keys, you don't have to type the password all the time ...